# Use of unassigned local variable LinqToLdap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, linq-to-ldap

I want to get list of users in my MVC.

Visual Studio keeps saying that I'm

> "Use of unassigned local variable 'model' ".

I've tried different methods but can't fix the error. Can anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong?.

```
 public ActionResult Search(string searchTerm)       
 {
        var users = new DirectorySource<UserModel>(ROOT,SearchScope.Subtree);

        IEnumerable<UserModel> model;

        var res = from usr in users
                  where usr.DisplayName.StartsWith(searchTerm)                     
                  select usr.DisplayName;

        foreach (var result in res)
        {
            model.OrderBy(p => p.DisplayName).ToList();
        }

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_search", model);
        }

        return View(model);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only declaring your `model`, but not instantiating it. You should instantiate it before trying to call methods on it (like `OrderBy`). Secondly, you should not perform the `OrderBy` inside a for loop, it's enough to do it only once. You might want to instantiate the `model` with the result of the Linq query and `select usr` at the end, not the display names.

```
var model = (from usr in users
            where usr.DisplayName.StartsWith(searchTerm)                     
            select usr).OrderBy(u => u.DisplayName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Error is very clear, you have to provide default value before usage.

```
IEnumerable<UserModel> model = new List<UserModel>();
```

or

```
IEnumerable<UserModel> model = null;
```

That is to take away your error, but you can simplify your code with below statement.

```
IEnumerable<UserModel> model =  users.Where(usr=>usr.DisplayName.StartsWith(searchTerm))
                                      .OrderBy(usr=>usr.DisplayName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
IEnumerable<UserModel> model;
```

try this:

```
List<UserModel> model = new List<UserModel>();
```

or:

```
IEnumerable<UserModel> model = new List<UserModel>();
```